# asp.net how to embed code from local text file (not AJAX)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, iis, include

I need to embed some html from a different server into my website.

I know that I could use a placeholde div, use jQuery to make an AJAX call and fill the placeholder with the parsed return data from AJAX, however in this scenario it has a noticable impact on the loading times of the website. Also the external code includes a small jQuery script, so the content has to be included into the page before the server delivers it to the browser, not later.

The idea is to have a cronjob script running that makes the AJAX call, does the parsing (adjusting paths, etc. so images and styles are shown correctly) and saves the result in a plain lokal text file.

Now I need a way to embed the code inside this text file in my asp.net / C# code (master page to be exact). How would I do that?

Thank you

Comment: So you want to load it on server and put it inside aspx file?

Comment: Basically yes. The local text file is on the server (/Includes/footer.txt for example) and I want the content of that file to be included into a predefined spot in the master page (/Masterpages/MasterPageNoSidebar.master for example).

Comment: I have found the solution here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306575/EN-US. `<% Response.WriteFile ("Yourfile.inc") %>` Does the trick.